# What is the error in the below Query?

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

I have written the below query in Drupal6.

```
$sql = 
    "SELECT registryvalue 
    FROM {muln_registry} 
    WHERE fk_applicationid = %d 
    AND registrykey = '%s'";

$result = db_result(db_query($sql, 32, 'SHOW_SCORE_TO_STUDENT'));
```

It is supposed to return the value 1. But it is not displaying anything. If i copy and run in mysql editor, it returns correctly.

But now it gives empty. No error in database connections etc. Because other queries are running perfectly.

What could be the error here?

Comment: Maybe display the query in your page to see if it's taking the variables correctly.

Comment: are you trying to search a string pattern?

Comment: @ophintor It takes values perfectly.

Comment: @RohitKumarChoudhary I am not trying to search a pattern. I want to get the status. It will be (1 or 0) in table

Comment: you need to count row or anything else?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data within the table?

Comment: var_dump($result) gives boolean false

Comment: can you check the value returned by the `db_query` call (remove the `db_result` as that will return `false` or a value)? As in, does the query call return `false` which indicates SQL-side problems?

Comment: db_query returns nothing.

Comment: kindly `var_dump` that, nothing has many different options -- is it false, null, or empty string ?

Comment: @hexblot var_dump($result) gives boolean false

Comment: from the [Drupal 6 documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database.mysql-common.inc/function/db_query/6) `db_query` returns `false` on failing queries. Check user permissions on your tables.

Comment: @EdwinAlex +1 for good question, but not getting preferable answer.

Comment: have you tried the Devel drupal module? Let you log queries directly from drupal.. https://drupal.org/project/devel

Answer (score 0):

All i can see the error is because of `{}`

should be

```
 $sql = "SELECT registryvalue FROM muln_registry WHERE fk_applicationid = %d AND registrykey = '%s'";
```

Comment: No. In Drupal we can access query like this. Even if i remove those parenthesis, i am not getting any output.

Comment: @EdwinAlex If you run the same query with `{}` is it gives result in `phpmyadmin`?

Comment: in phpmyadmin, we can't run like this. I removed {} and executed. It gives the exact output.

Answer (score 0):

Try a

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump(db_query($sql, 32, 'SHOW_SCORE_TO_STUDENT'));
echo '</pre>';
```

And see what data is in the handle. This may give you a better idea of what is going wrong. My suggestion is to switch to PDO but I know that is not going to be a valid option when a system already uses a different DB mechanism.

Comment: ewww just looked at the connection type in drupal 6 to make sure i wasnt talking out my ass in suggesting the use of PDO and they dont even use mysqli [view source](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database.mysql.inc/6)

Answer (score 0):

If 'SHOW_SCORE_TO_STUDENT' is the same every time why not use:

```
$sql = "SELECT registryvalue FROM {muln_registry} WHERE fk_applicationid = '%d' AND registrykey = 'SHOW_SCORE_TO_STUDENT'";
```

Also you have ' ' around the second parameter but not the first one, not sure if that might be the problem?

Comment: First one is integer value and second one is varchar type. Also if we use your query, it leads to SQL injection. This is vulnerable.

Comment: Why would this lead to an SQL injection? your passing the only parameter the same way as in the original query, and the value for registrykey can't be changed by the user?

Comment: I dont see any difference between these two. SHOW_SCORE_TO_STUDENT is a constant. It can be changed according to the configuration settings. So can pass like that also.

Answer (score -1):

You should try LIKE operator for searching a patter. Eg
`WHERE column_name LIKE '%searchString'` will search where record start with searchString.

For more information on Like you can search for it.

Comment: I am not searching any pattern. I just want to get the output 1 (or) 0. For that i am comparing one id and string

Comment: Ok , I am sorry. have you var_dump($result)?

Comment: LIKE is not always needed, the = is perfectly valid if that is what they intend

Answer (score -2):

please use:

```
$sql     = "SELECT registryvalue FROM muln_registry WHERE fk_applicationid = %d AND registrykey = '%s'";
```

instead of

```
$sql     = "SELECT registryvalue FROM {muln_registry} WHERE fk_applicationid = %d AND registrykey = '%s'";
```

{} curly braces have been removed.

Comment: this is plain wrong for Drupal 6 -- you ARE supposed to use `{}` so that Drupal may rewrite table names with prefixes if needed. Plus, if you read the comments below, this has been tried and has not worked for debugging.